# Replacing data in text files

Tags: text-processing

I have two files

file1:

```
 world,11
```

file2:

```
hello welcome to the ("12345,67")
```

I am trying to replace the above `"(12345,67)"` with `"world,11"`

Comment: Please give a clear example of existing input files and expected output.

Comment: You need to make your question way more specific, e.g. provide actual snippets from both files, otherwise answers are bound to be innacurate. Please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/319297/edit) your post.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please give an input/output examples.

Comment: I guess you are looking for somethind like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script

Answer (score 1):

According to what you posted I think that this code will solve your problem:

```
replacement=`cat replacement.txt`
content=`cat content.txt`
pattern="pattern"
echo "${content//$pattern/$replacement}" # all strings matching will be replaced with $replacement
echo "${content/$pattern/$replacement}" # the first string matching the pattern will be replaced
```